# Build make target if contents of directory have changed

Tags: makefile, prerequisites

I need a Makefile that allows me to enter `make foo-program` and, if any `foo-program/**/*.hs` file has changed since last build, build the target (output in `foo-program/.stack-work`).

Here is my directory tree:

```
project/
|-bar-other-program/
  |-.stack-work/ # Generated output goes here
  |-src/
    |-BarOtherProgram.hs
  |-test/
    |-Tests.hs
|-foo-program/
  |-.stack-work/ # Generated output goes here
  |-src/
    |-FooProgram.hs
  |-test/
    |-Tests.hs
|-notes/ # non-source, so no Make target for this
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
# evaluates to 'bar-other-program foo-program'
PROGS := $(shell find * -type f -name '*.hs' | cut -d'/' -f1 | uniq)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(PROGS): $$(wildcard $$@/src/*.hs) $$(wildcard $$@/test/*.hs)
    # do-build $@
```

When I run `make foo-program`, whether the source has changed or not, I get:

```
make: Nothing to be done for 'foo-program'
```

UPDATE: My final (non-abstracted) Makefile can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/cmccandless/ExercismSolutions-haskell/blob/f3a8165433b24853c4c22c165e218858026f951d/Makefile). Note that my solution took a different turn than I intended when I wrote up this question. Looking at that Makefile also might also make it more clear as to my original goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure of the the purpose of `cut -d'/'` there.

But if you just want a list of `*.hs` files in the current directory (recursively found) and then build a target/executable based on whether they have changed, you can do something like this:

```make
PROGS = $(subst ./,,$(shell find . -type f -name '*.hs'))
DEPS = $(addprefix stackwork/,$(addsuffix .dep,$(basename $(PROGS))))
DIRS = $(dir $(DEPS))

.PHONY: foo-program
foo-program: $(DEPS) $(DIRS)

stackwork/%.dep: %.hs | $(DIRS)
    @echo making $@
    @touch $@

$(DIRS):
    @echo creating dir $@
    @mkdir -p $@

clean:
    @rm -rf $(DEPS) $(DIRS)
```

Where:

- `PROGS` is your list of `.hs` files
- `DEPS` is a list of generated dependency files (empty but date stamps will be used)
- `DIRS` is a list of output directories that need to be created (I guess they don't exist by default since they are output folders?)
- `foo-program` is a rule that you can call (`PHONY` because at the moment it does not create a real file)
- `%.dep: %.hs` is a rule how to generate a .dep file (this could be a .o .obj or any other file type) which depends on its .hs file equivalent.
- `$(DIRS)`: is a rule to create your output directories if needed.

So if the `.dep` files don't exist, all of the `.hs` files will be "compiled". If all the `.dep` files exist and are up to date, then nothing will be compiled. If one or more file is out of date then just those files will be built. Here is the output of running this on my PC with a few test files:

```
admin@osboxes:~/sandbox$ make
    creating dir stackwork/
    creating dir stackwork/test/
    creating dir stackwork/test/test2/
    making stackwork/file.dep
    making stackwork/test/file.dep
    making stackwork/test/test2/file2.dep

admin@osboxes:~/sandbox$ make
    make: Nothing to be done for 'foo-program'.

admin@osboxes:~/sandbox$ touch test/file.hs      
admin@osboxes:~/sandbox$ make
    making stackwork/test/file.dep

admin@osboxes:~/sandbox$ make
    make: Nothing to be done for 'foo-program'.
```

Comment: Marked as answer because it got me closest to what I want... I realized I was missing some details in my problem description. I ended up going a different route.

Comment: @cmac it might be useful (for later readers) to post up your updated version if its useful? I would also suggest testing your new makefile with `make -j4` (or whatever -j value you want) to make sure the order of dependencies works for parallel builds : )